# Android service in Delphi

Tags: android, delphi, service

I've been trying for a couple of days write an Android service using Delphi Seattle, but every time the App crash and stop responding. My service needs to use an UDP connection to send messages to the server.

Here's a simple example I wrote.

Host App

```
unit Unit3;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Types, System.UITypes, System.Classes, System.Variants,
  FMX.Types, FMX.Controls, FMX.Forms, FMX.Graphics, FMX.Dialogs,
  FMX.Controls.Presentation, FMX.StdCtrls, System.Android.Service;

type
  TForm3 = class(TForm)
    Start: TButton;
    procedure StartClick(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
    ConexaoServico : TLocalServiceConnection;
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form3: TForm3;

implementation

{$R *.fmx}

procedure TForm3.StartClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ConexaoServico := TLocalServiceConnection.Create;
  ConexaoServico.StartService('Servicoteste');
end;

end.
```

Service

```
unit AndroidServicoteste;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils,
  System.Classes,
  System.Android.Service,
  AndroidApi.JNI.GraphicsContentViewText,
  Androidapi.JNI.Os, IdBaseComponent, IdComponent, IdUDPBase, IdUDPClient;

type
  TAndroidServiceDM = class(TAndroidService)
    IdUDPClient1: TIdUDPClient;
    function AndroidServiceStartCommand(const Sender: TObject;
      const Intent: JIntent; Flags, StartId: Integer): Integer;
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  AndroidServiceDM: TAndroidServiceDM;

implementation

{%CLASSGROUP 'FMX.Controls.TControl'}

{$R *.dfm}
uses
  Androidapi.JNI.App;

function TAndroidServiceDM.AndroidServiceStartCommand(const Sender: TObject;
  const Intent: JIntent; Flags, StartId: Integer): Integer;
begin

  IdUDPClient1.Connect;
  IdUDPClient1.Send('Teste', nil);
  IdUDPClient1.Host:= '192.168.1.109';
  IdUDPClient1.Port:= 45001;
  Result:= TJService.JavaClass.START_STICKY;
end;

end.
```

When I press Start (TButton), I get nothing in the server.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Shouldn't you assign the `IdUDPClient1.Host` and `IdUDPClient1.Port` before you call `IdUDPClient1.Connect;` and `IdUDPClient1.Send('Teste', nil);`?

Comment: Yes, you need to assign the `Host`/`Port` properties before calling `Connect()`. On the other hand, you don't need to use `Connect()` in the first place, you can pass the `Host`/`Port` values directly to `Send()` instead: `IdUDPClient1.Send('192.168.1.109', 45001, 'Teste', nil);`

Comment: Note, the Android documentation for [`onStartCommand`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#onStartCommand%28android.content.Intent,%20int,%20int%29) warns: "*Note that the system calls this on your service's main thread. A service's main thread is the same thread where UI operations take place for Activities running in the same process. You should always avoid stalling the main thread's event loop. When doing long-running operations, **network calls**, or heavy disk I/O, you should **kick off a new thread, or use AsyncTask**.*"

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem then i try IdHTTP in service.
I think the problem is in FMX.Helpers.Android because it use Activity.
IdComponent use IdStack. (line 69)
IdStack use FMX.Helpers.Android (line 438)

PS. Delphi RX Seattle

Comment: ^ It's not answer, it's comment. Sorry